# Analysis I Foundations question

Tags: analysis

. For any natural number n, let $P_n$ be the statement that $n^3 + n + 1$ is even.

i. Show that for every natural number $n  \in \mathbb N$, we have that $P_n\implies P_{n+1}$

ii. Show that $P_n$ is always false.

What is going on here, and how does this relate to induction

Answer (score 0):

You are showing that a particular "inductive step" is valid.  What is missing is the base case.  Notice that $P_1$ is false because $1^3 + 1 + 1 = 3$ is not even.

Recall that one interprets an inductive proof along the model :

- If the claim is true for $1$ then it is true for $2$.
- If the claim is true for $2$ then it is true for $3$.
- $\vdots$ (and so on, forever)

Notice that the stack of sentences above are all conditional : if something is true then something else is true.  This requires that at some point we can write

- The claim is true for $1$.

No condition; no dependence on some other version of the claim.  At some point, we need the fact that the claim **actually is true** at least once.  Then we get an infinitely long chain of consequences where the claim is true for all larger integers.

An easy way to show that $n^3 + n + 1$ is always not even is to see what it does to an even $n$ and an odd $n$.  Since every natural number is either even or odd, we (will have) shown that the claim is false for all natural numbers.